# Can't load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains. Django Facebook Auth

Tags: python, django, facebook-login, django-socialauth

I have been using facebook login for my Django App. Recently facebook had updated its security feature, by enabling Strict Mode for all apps. After this change users are not able to login into site as it says below error

> Can't load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's
>   domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and sub-domains
>   of your app to the App Domains field in your app setting

But the domain name in App domain setting is fine. I think i am doing mistake in redirct_uri setting. I read lot of discussion on Facebook Developers group , but couldn't found the solution. Can anyone please help me out 
[image]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your fb app settings and also the url on which the error is showing

Comment: sure @ArpitSolanki , please check this url : https://www.edyoda.com/User/login/

Comment: I'm getting this same problem

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Finally figured this out!
On the page where your error comes up (screenshot below) you will notice a url parameter called "redirect_uri" You need to copy this text, then decode it using a site like this: [url-encode-decode.com](https://www.url-encode-decode.com/). Finally you will need to use that exact text as your "Valid oauth redirect URIs" field.

[image: error message]

**Important:** At first, when I did this, I noticed that the `redirect_uri` parameter contained a parameter called `redirect_state`, which changed each time you log in.

This makes it impossible to list ALL the Redirect URIs in Facebook Login Configuration. If you see a `redirect_state` parameter, you will need to update your `social-auth-core` Python package to a version > 1.6 (I got this information from [here](https://github.com/python-social-auth/social-app-django/issues/112))

Once you do that, you will have a Redirect URI without parameters on the Facebook error page, which will work for you.

The following are working for me AFTER updating to `social-auth-core` version 1.7:

[image: working redirect uris]

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to developer.facebook.com
2. Add redirect URL

[image]
[image]